# Storing runtime configuration of storm topology

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-storm

My storm topology has some runtime parameters. e.g. kafka topic to listen from, kafka consumer group id etc. if 5 months after topology deployment someone wants to check what parameters were used, it would be good to have them accessible in runtime. on nimbus web page or somewhere else. i know i can just log them but logs are rotated.

how it's usually done? or what's the storm's way of achieving this?

Comment: If you already use Kafka in your cluster you have to use Zookeeper too. So, I would recommend to use Zookeeper as a centralized configuration storage for user configuration properties. In this case all configuration properties will be accessible by using Zookeeper CLI or some kind of UI client.

Comment: is it somehow supported by storm? any exposed api or i have to program it all by myself?

Comment: As I know internally Storm has integration with Zookeeper, but in your case you have to implement a required logic by yourself.